# ACDSee does not show categories of images

Tags: acdsee

ACDSee shows special blue bookmark icon above image thumbnail, meaning this image belongs to some category:

[image]

Unfortunately, this category is not highlighted in the category list, and this is not shown if its category is selected (I just added category and am sure image is of it).

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

Version 6.3 build 221

Comment: Which ACDSee version?

Comment: See my update please